How can I see the effective configuration of built-in TypeScript Server in VSCode
There is a built-in TypeScript server in VSCode.
ts --showConfig
command shows the effective TypeScript configuration for the project, it will output the merged configuration from your tsconfig.json file and any default TypeScript settings.
But how can I get showConfig of the built-in TS Server? Above command will show the configuration of the system-wide TypeScript, not the built-in TS Server.
